# apollo graphql's subscription on rails + actioncable + redis pubsub

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, graphql, actioncable, apollostack

I am trying to archive graphql subscription using [apollo](http://dev.apollodata.com/) + Rails actioncable (redis pubsub backend).

## problem

Currently, I am using [graphql-ruby](https://github.com/rmosolgo/graphql-ruby) and doing `query` and `mutation` fine, but the gem doesn't support `subscription`.

## thoughts

I only have a minor knowledge about graphql and redis, and so this may sound foolish but I am thinking if I set up a separated graphql server (only for `subscription`) that is connected to the same redis database that the rails is using, broadcasting from rails' actioncable to the redis should be picked up by the graphql server?

[image]

### rails

sends a hash data through `broadcast` as usual, no changes.

```rb
ActionCable.server.broadcast(...)
```

### separated graphql server

setup a graphql server using [GraphQL subscriptions with Redis Pub Sub](https://dev-blog.apollodata.com/graphql-subscriptions-with-redis-pub-sub-f636fc84a0c4#.a3wrjxbfu) somehow, and wait for the rails' broadcastings through redis.

## is this all workable?

or are there other possible ways to impliment graphql subscription in rails?